# SQL join two tables that have the same columns, with an overlapping `id` column, but merge based on if table1.col1 >= table2.col1

Tags: sql, join

I want to join two tables that have the same columns, with an overlapping `id` column, but merge based on if table1.col1 >= table2.col1. This is in SQL.

1. If table1.col1>=table2.col1, use the columns from table1.
2. If table1.col1< table2.col1, then use columns from table2.
3. If the `id` does not exist in table1 but exists in table2, use the columns from table2
4. If the `id` does not exist in table2 but exists in table1, use the columns from table1

For example:
Table1:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| C | 8 | 9 | 7 |

Table2:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 5 | 6 |
| B | 5 | 7 | 8 |
| D | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I want the result to be:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| B | 5 | 7 | 8 |
| C | 8 | 9 | 7 |
| D | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I have tried union, full outer join, and CASE statements, but am stuck

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think individual `case` expressions for each column might be best:

```
select id,
       (case when t1.col1 < t2.col1 then t2.col1 else t1.col1 end) as col1,
       (case when t1.col1 < t2.col1 then t2.col2 else t1.col2 end) as col2,
       (case when t1.col1 < t2.col1 then t2.col3 else t1.col3 end) as col3
from t1 full join
     t2
     using (id);
```

If that is cumbersome, another approach uses `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.col1 > t1.col1
                 )
union all
select t2.*
from t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from t1
                  where t2.id = t1.id and t1.col1 >= t2.col1
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    ) AS aux
ORDER BY id, col1 DESC;
```

I tried it in Postgresql.